# How represent edge weight via JGraphT visualization?

Tags: java, jgrapht

I tried create a Java JGraphT visualization with Weight, for example:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXRrc.png]

Now I want to change the edge label (ex: (a:b) to its edge weight (ex: 2).
I tried to search in Javadoc but didn't see anything.
Please help me thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Those edge labels came from the `toString` method of the edge object. Therefore you may create your own edge class and override the `toString` method in such a way that it yields the edge weight.

You may create your custom edge like this:

```
class MyWeightedEdge extends DefaultWeightedEdge {
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return Double.toString(getWeight());
  }
}
```

And then create your graph like this which will make the graph create edges as instances of `MyDefaultEdge` and therefore display just edge weight in the visualization:

```
SimpleWeightedGraph<String,MyWeightedEdge> graph
  = new SimpleWeightedGraph<String,MyWeightedEdge>(MyWeightedEdge.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

JGraphT is implemented Generic so when you pass Edge class just implement toString() method in your respective class. 
E.g. suppose "City" is my Vertex class and "Path" is my Edge so implement toString() method in that

```
class Pathe{
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Distant Between" +this.source +"this.dest" "is" + this.distance;
  }
}
```